# New to pandas and looking for help replicating an Excel function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames with schemas as below

df1 =

| First_name | Second_name | team_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Granit | Xhaka | Arsenal |
| Kalvin | Phillips | Man City |

df2 =

| home_team | team_away |
| --- | --- |
| Arsenal | Leeds |
| Brentford | Man City |

I want to replicate the following excel formula. It matches the team_name column from df1 to the home_team column in df2 and then copys the team in the.team_away column from the same row and adds it to a new column in df1 called GW1, if their is not a match for the row it then checks the team_name column for a match in the team_away column. If there is a match it then copys the value from the home_team into the same GW1 column
the result should look like

| First_name | Second_name | team_name. | GW1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Granit | Xhaka | Arsenal. | Leeds |
| Kalvin | Phillips | Man City | Brentford |

The excel function is
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2,C$11:D$17,2,FALSE),INDEX(C$11:C$17,MATCH(F2,D$11:D$17,0)))

I've tried a merge function but although i can get close, i cannot replicate the function as above.

Comment: @QuangHoang this is not a simple merge, OP needs to preprocess a bit the reference to have the key/value also as value/key

Answer (score 0):

Create a duplication of the reversed reference with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to have both the home or away team to act as key, then `merge`:

```
df1.merge(pd.concat([df2.rename(columns={'home_team': 'team_name', 'team_away': 'GW1'}),
                     df2.rename(columns={'home_team': 'GW1', 'team_away': 'team_name'})]),
          on='team_name', how='left')
```

Output:

```
  First_name Second_name team_name        GW1
0     Granit       Xhaka   Arsenal      Leeds
1     Kalvin    Phillips  Man City  Brentford
```

Comment: thanks for this. It has worked perfectly, i would never of pulled this together but i can see the premise when looking at the documentation.

Comment: @rob you're welcome, don't hesitate to ask if you have questions.